# how to generate sql script file from C# codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, scripting

How to generate sql script file from C# codebehind? The script file will contain **create** and **drop** statement of a storedproc in the db.

How to generate the script from db in C# and write to an .sql file?

Is it possible to generate script of create and drop statement of table or storedproc from db in C#

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i've understood correctly, set up a `SqlCommand` object with the following

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection ("Connection String Here"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_helptext @procName";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("procName", "Name Of Stored Proc Here");

        con.Open(); 

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                /* 
                    You will get the CREATE PROC text here
                    Do what you need to with it. For example, write
                    to a .sql file
                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will return the text of a stored procedure as a `CREATE PROC` statement, in a result set where each row of the resultset is a line of the stored procedure.

To create a `DROP PROC` statement, simply write out

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'procName') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROC procName
```

to a `.sql` file.

Comment: Great. But can u help me so that I can generate create statement for tables,functions,views? Please help.

Comment: It's really helped me. Now I need to generate create statements for tables. I am able to generate create statement for views functions and sp, but can't generate for tables. Please help.

Comment: I'm not aware of a system stored procedure that will script out a table structure as `sp_helptext` does for user defined functions, sporcs or views (amongst other objects) or like you can do in SSMS with "Script As..." option. Looking in Sql Profiler at what happens when you use that option in SSMS may yield a way forward for tables.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [SQL Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) - a .NET library for working with SQL Server.

What you're trying to accomplish is fairly straightforward.  The C# code for your immediate stored procedure question is something like (where you write the script to a .SQL text file instead of the console)

```
Server theServer = new Server("myServerName");
Database myDB = theServer.Databases["myDatabaseName"];

StoredProcedure sp = myDB.StoredProcedures["mySprocName", "dbo"];

StringCollection sc = sp.Script();

foreach (string s in sc)
  Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This code excerpt is taken from an article entitled [Scripting Database Objects using SMO](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated) by Bill Graziano

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, there's probably a safer and easier way to do what you want than the method you're proposing.  You can build a SQL statement in code, set up a [SQLCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) object, and execute your SQL statement directly, for instance.

Comment: I want to get the create statement of a storedproc from the db using C#. I need the create statement from db will be generated from C# codebehind.

Comment: Do you want to create a SQL statement, or retrieve an existing stored procedure from the database?

Comment: I don't want to copy create statement from sql server management studio but I want to fetch the create statement in C# codebehind using sqlcommand. The statements are not inserted into a database table created by me. System tables can help or any other options will be appriciated

Comment: I want to retrieve existing stored procedures create drop statement.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the schema of the table but you're just changing the name of the table, you'd need to get a copy of the CREATE script (obtainable from sql management studio quite easily) and drop that into your code-behind file, and then save it as a .sql file using a text writer or something...

Answer (score -1):

I don't really have the knowledge in SQL Server but the results of the following queries might help you:

```
select * from information_schema.columns
select * from information_schema.tables
select * from sysobjects
```