# How to retrieve create statement for table from db in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, scripting

How to retrieve create statement for table from db in C#?

I need to create a script file containing create statement
for an existing table in db using C#.

I can generate create statement of storedproc using [**sp_helptext**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576913/how-to-generate-sql-script-file-from-c-codebehind) but can't generate it for table.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported for tables although a quick google gives a script

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/28eeb603-1607-4b56-9461-3c0502cbec9c

Answer (score 2):

this is joke.

1. use sqlmetal.exe and compile output.
2. use DataContext.CreateDatabase (use
   Log property of DataContext to get SQL Code)

Comment: can't understand your answer.

Comment: sqlmetal.exe is command-line tool for LINQ to SQL. that extract metadata(table structure, etc) from SQL server to DataContext class source-code.
DataContext class has a CreateDatabase Method & Log property. CreateDatabase was execute a CREATE TABLE statement. and Log property for see that statements.